# Toggle Core Location on and off based on date

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

Hi i am developing an app that uses core location in the background and inform users with a location notification push.

I use the following code to register for significant location changes.

```
 CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]
 autorelease];
 [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

And running a background task when update to location.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
  fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

But this feature is only needed for particular day of the week. Is it possible to set a timer for the CLLocationManager to be active only for particular day of the week?

For example turn on significant location change for monday only, the rest of the week keep signification location change off.

EDIT: To clarify, looking to turn off the location services (same as calling [locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges] ), ie. the gps symbol is only activated on Monday, and on the other days the gps symbol is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:toDay];
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
if (weekday == 2) {
    // It is monday
} else {
    // It is another day of the week
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But im looking to turn off the locationManager all together on  non affected days. Is that possible?

Comment: You can do that in the else statement. When your app launches, test which day it is and turn the locationManager on or off.

Comment: If the user choose not to launch the app, there is no way to go around this? Much like the reminder app, when u set a particular date + a location, the gps is not activated until the stated date is reached.

Comment: If the user doesn't launch the app, there is not much you can. There might be exceptions for location based apps (while the app is in the background but not closed) but I have no experience on that. Sorry.